# What is wrong with the following Postgresql query?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

The query:

```
CREATE TABLE unapprovedteaminfo (
UnapprovedTeamInfoID        BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
EmailVerified               boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
VerificationCode            char (20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (UnapprovedTeamInfoID)
);
```

The error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "(" Position: 160 [ERROR:0, SQLSTATE:42601]
```

Might I add that pointing out the location of the error by "position" (instead of column and row) is unbelievably annoying?

Comment: No problems here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/91178/1

Comment: If you are using psql, make sure you enter \r<enter> before entering the query so your query starts where you think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with the DDL query. I just executed it without problem in my 9.1.5 installation.

The reason must be something that is not in your question.

As an aside: I assume you are aware, that unquoted identifiers are cast to lower case.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what error you are getting as the same query is working perfectly fine for me.

Have a look [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/78859)

There may be other reason not mentioned here.

The error you mentioned here occurs when:

> A comment is not closed correctly with a comment delimiter. The
>   comment is treated as if it were closed by the end of source file.

Look [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzala%2Frzalaml.htm) for the description of your error.